# Defining keyframe animations inside media queries

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to get objects to "slide in" from the bottom of the screen, but since I can't get the screen height as a unit in CSS, I'm trying to do this with media queries, like so:

```
@media(max-height:500px) {
  @keyframe slideUp {
    0%    { transform: translate3d(0,500px,0); }
    100%  { transform: translate3d(0,0,0); }
  }
}
@media(max-height:750px) {
  @keyframe slideUp {
    0%    { transform: translate3d(0,750px,0); }
    100%  { transform: translate3d(0,0,0); }
  }
}
/* etc. */
```

This doesn't work (it uses the first version of `slideUp` regardless of height), so I assume keyframes, once defined, cannot be overwritten or reassigned based on media queries? Is there any way to achieve this effect (short of having many different keyframe setups and using a media query to assign the appropriate one to the class)?

Comment: @adrift [As of CSS 3, nested `At`-rules are permitted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/At-rule). CSS2.1 is from 1998 btw, so it's very obsolete now.

Comment: @Dai: Deleted, thanks for updating me.

Comment: I had a different animation, but your code worked for me 100% fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 67):

I don't know why no one else has suggested this, but instead of setting the keyframes in the media query you can set the animation in the media query.

```
@media(max-height:500px) 
{
    #selectorGroup {
        animation: slideUp500 1s forwards;
    }
}

@media(max-height:750px) 
{
    #selectorGroup {
        animation: slideUp750 1s forwards;
    }
}


@keyframes slideUp500 {
    0%    { transform: translate3d(0,500px,0); }
    100%  { transform: translate3d(0,0,0); }
}

@keyframes slideUp750 {
    0%    { transform: translate3d(0,750px,0); }
    100%  { transform: translate3d(0,0,0); }
}
```

Comment: Looking again - I see you did suggest this in the original question, but for some situations this my be the only way

Comment: It sucks that you have to semi-duplicate the code, but works.

Comment: @Kyle Hawk take a minute and go look at the messy CSS for any of the top websites out there. That should make you feel better about it :)

Answer (score 17):

Nowadays you can solve this using native CSS variables.

In your case:

```
@media(max-height:500px) {
    :root {
        --slide-up-y: 500px
    }
}

@media(max-height:750px) {
    :root {
        --slide-up-y: 750px
    }
}

@keyframes slideUp {
    0%    { transform: translate3d(0,var(--slide-up-y),0); }
    100%  { transform: translate3d(0,0,0); }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A way of doing a slide up animation regardless of screen or element height is to use `position: fixed`:

```
.box {
    position: fixed;
    animation: slideUp 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes slideUp {
    from { top: 100%; }
    to { top: 0; }
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/Kvtd2/

If you want to slide relative to a parent element and not the viewport, use `position: absolute` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, it needs to be fast on mobile devices, which means I need to use a 3d transform to get hardware acceleration. Otherwise I'd be doing this.

Comment: I see. I have just posted another answer for that purpose. It requires some experimentation to get the results you want, but I hope you'll find it helpful.

Comment: do you have example of sliding relative to parent element? seems that more than `position: absolute` is needed http://jsfiddle.net/ypuun2xL/

Comment: @Simon_Weaver you mainly need a `position: relative` on the parent as well. Here are two different ways of achieving this (it can get more complicated/simple depending on your needs): http://jsfiddle.net/ypuun2xL/3/ and http://jsfiddle.net/ypuun2xL/4/

Answer (score 2):

Long time since this question was asked. But I'm seeing that nobody has answered the solution that I'll give you, and this one, in my opinion, is easier than creating different `media-queries` for different screen sizes.

@myajouri proposed you to use a `fixed` position and you discarded this solution because you need to use 3d transforms to get hardware acceleration. But you can still use 3d transforms with a fixed position. With `CSS` transformations, if you use percentages, they will be relative to the size of the element itself. This will allow you to move the element from outside the screen no matter what size it has, so, only one keyframe animation is needed. Check the next snippet:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.element {
  animation: slideUp 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  background: #CCC;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

@keyframes slideUp {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="element" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use `translate3d` to get hardware acceleration on mobile devices (as you mentioned), and given that you can't use at-rules inside `@media`:

You could define one `@keyframes` with large `translateX` (say `5000px`) and change the `animation-duration` based on the screen height to ensure the speed is more or less the same across the different heights.

I would also define height ranges (`max-height` and `min-height`) as opposed to upper limits (`max-height` only) to prevent unwanted style overrides.

```
@keyframes slideUp {
    from { transform: translate3d(0,5000px,0); }
    to   { transform: translate3d(0,0,0); }
}

.box { animation: slideUp 5s forwards; }

@media (min-height: 0) and (max-height: 500px) {
    .box { animation-duration: 0.5s; }
}

@media (min-height: 501px) and (max-height: 750px) {
    .box { animation-duration: 0.75s; }
}

@media (min-height: 751px) and (max-height: 1000px) {
    .box { animation-duration: 1s; }
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/9xLyf/