# How to define screen media queries inside animation's @keyframe block in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to define screen media queries inside animation's @keyframe block in SASS? I mean like this sample (doesn't work):

```
@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    background: #512da8;
  }
  50% {
    background: #512da8;
    top: 26px;
  }
  100% {
    background: #311b92;
    width: 100%;

    @media(max-width: 1000px) {
        height: 250px;        
    } 

    // @include media(max-width: 1000px) {
    //     height: 50px;
    // }

    border-radius: 0px;
    top: 26px;
  }
}
```

I am investigating a way written like above, not written like this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29224702/12698480

Comment: Nope. There isn't.

Comment: @roberrrt-s thank your robert. Maybe someone finds a less code way later on

Comment: Keyframes can't contain media queries. You'll need to use media queries to define different variants of the keyframes.

Comment: You need to create your media query, then add your keyframes to that. Write your keyframe in the file, then address it in whatever code you add to your media query